# Efficiently Intersecting Big Boolean Arrays

Tags: arrays, optimization, boolean, intersect, memory-efficient

Suppose I have **N** Boolean arrays of size **M**. I simply want to intersect between pairs of these Boolean arrays efficiently (in optimized time). In my problem in hand, **N** is at least equal to 4500 and **M** is always equal to 6040. How can I make my intersection operator as fast as possible (an algorithmic idea)? Also any idea how can I manage such big arrays in memory?

My current implementation is in PHP, but its possible to migrate to Java in case of benefit.

Comment: In fact, intersecting is not that much heavy operator. But as in my problem, it should be done many times, so I would like to make it as fast as possible.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but in Java [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) is an option to have every boolean only consume 1 bit (PHP probably has something similar), though that's still not going to be particularly efficient. Algorithmic improvement? I doubt it, we're too far down the process for that. Compiler optimization, maybe (but don't ask me and don't expect too much). The usual advice when you try to force something inefficient - You may want to take 2 steps back and try to find a completely different way to solve your problem.

Comment: Memory should be no problem, even if each boolean takes a byte, that's like 30 MB.